# Accessing files from custom directories to Django

Tags: python, html, django, backend, django-3.2

I am fairly new to Django. Currently, I am making a Django 3.2 web server. Here is the concerned directory structure:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LtJ6.png

**Problem**

I want to display the images in the `generated\images` folder in `results.html`. What should I do to make it so? Just for more info, the `emotionchecker` is a Django app.

I really am new, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't generate those images there. Generate them in the media directory of your project (you might be able to make some hacks now if you try but later while deploying you will face more difficulties)

Comment: Sir is there any default media directory path in Django? A little help will be appreciated.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/